# how to add html page in wordpress page partially

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress.
I want to partially render some html code to wordpress page from admin section.

Description : i have a file menu.php with contains some html elements.
Is it possible to inject this file to a page from admin section while editing page information.

Many Thanks.

M

Answer (score 0):

[1] You can simply add html code/elements in the page/post. Have a look to this screenshot: https://www.diigo.com/item/p/rapdderzccaddbecazbecorocb

OR [2] You can create a template as described below :
Duplicate post.php or page.php in your theme folder (under /wp-content/themes/themename/).

Rename the new file as templatename.php (where templatename is what you want to call your new template!). Enter the following at the top of the new file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: templatename
*/
?>
```

You can modify this file (using php) to include other files or whatever you need.

Then create a new page in your WordPress blog, and in the page editing screen you'll see a 'Template' dropdown in the 'Attributes' widget to the right. Select your new template and publish the page.

Your new page will use the php code defined in templatename.php

Comment: Thanks Dipak G... This is not what i am looking for..I want to inject a external php file in page via admin.